# Kitty's next meeting

Tags: geography

Agent Kitty has been returned to London where a decision will be made what to do with her. She will be taken to the head of her secret service - Z - for him to make the final call. All she has been told is that the meeting will take place in the southernmost part of European territory that can be reached by land from London (including the Channel Tunnel obviously). So where will they end up?

Comment: is this really a puzzle? isn't it just trivia/knowledge?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a trivia question.

Comment: With the territory part, I think it was a puzzle at all.

Answer (score 9):

Places that "*can be reached by land from London*" cover the whole of mainland Europe, Asia, and Africa. Being "*European territory*" presumably includes places that are considered the territory of a European country despite not being part of the main contiguous block of the country, as shown on [this map](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-gv-IH69VYyY/U2Uk1lJuBdI/AAAAAAAAAFw/NExLjPdnqrI/s1600/european_union_overseas_outermost_territories_map.png) for instance. I think the answer is probably

> one of [the Spanish enclaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plazas_de_soberan%C3%ADa) in North Africa.

of which the southernmost appears to be

> [Melilla](https://www.google.co.nz/maps/place/Melilla,+Spain)

Comment: I was about to dispute this with Znpnh, but turns out I'm 20 years of date...

Comment: Rot13 in place of spoiler tag

Comment: Oh darn, my Rot13-fu is lacking. I thought z <-> n. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

This meeting will occur at:

> [Punta de Tarifa, Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punta_de_Tarifa)

which is the southernmost part of mainland Europe, according to:

> [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_points_of_Europe#Mainland_Europe), which mentions that although an island, it is now connected to the mainland by a causeway.

Comment: European *territory* :-)

Comment: Yeah, just seen your answer, nice one :-)